# What would be an example to optimize code that was supposed to work without useMemo, using useMemo()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In React's Hooks API, it was suggested that future react implementation may choose to forget memorized values and that the code should work before optimization with useMemo().

My question is, what would be a good example in which the code works without useMemo(), performs better with useMemo, and continue to work if useMemo forget memorized values?

You can visit the original page [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), a screenshot is also posted in case the page is updated in the future.
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that is example is contrived.

```
function App() {
  let [first, setFirst] = React.useState(1);
  let [second, setSecond] = React.useState(1);
  let [sum, setSum] = React.useState(undefined);

  let total = function expensive(x, y) {
    console.log("computing");
    return parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
  };

  let add = () => {
    setSum(total);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        onChange={e => setFirst(e.target.value)}
        type="number"
        value={first}
      />
      <input
        onChange={e => setSecond(e.target.value)}
        type="number"
        value={second}
      />
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
      <h2>{sum}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you run this code, and smash the "ADD" button, you'll notice that "computing" logs every time, even though `first` and `second` have not changed. This code works without using `useMemo`, but is not optimal. There's an optimization we can make.

Consider this change:

```
 let total = React.useMemo(function expensive(x, y) {
   console.log("computing");
   return parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
 }, [first, second]);
```

Notice that "computing" only logs once, as the return value is being memoized. It will only recalculate when `first` or `second` changes. This will continue to work without `useMemo`.

Examples like this are exactly what `useMemo` is for -- a simple optimization. With or without that your code would still be run just fine.

"You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization" - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Hope this helps! :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-chandrasekhar-nzqfx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark